# Как в списке в json командой удалить айди пользователя?

Tags: discord.py

Пример:
Фаил users.json в нём есть [айди, айди, т.д...], как мне командой, заставить убрать айди то котрое я укажу? Если можно то напешите подробно!
idT - список этих айди
idO - является само айди в списке

Comment: idO точней это айди которое я указываю после команды*

Answer (score 0):

```
from json import load, dump
from discord.ext import commands


@commands.command()
async def removeID(ctx: commands.Context, id):
    with open("users.json", 'r') as f:
        idT = load(f)

    del idT[id]

    with open("users.json", 'w') as f:
        dump(idT, f)
```